# iOS: dismissViewControllerAnimated crashes upon execution

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have below code that will call a modal view. I works fine when presenting the view controller but when i dismiss it, it crashes

```
_surveySummaryTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[_surveySummaryTableViewController setTableView:_surveySummaryTableView];

UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(closeModalView:)];
[[_surveySummaryTableViewController navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:doneItem];
[[_surveySummaryTableViewController navigationItem] setTitle:@"Response Summary"];

navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_surveySummaryTableViewController];
[navController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[navController setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

....

[self presentViewController:navController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Clicking on the DONE button on the modal view will call the `closeModalView:` method below:

```
- (void)closeModalView:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The weird part is, when I comment out the line below, the dismiss works fine. But of cause, the view will be empty without any `TableView`. What could I have missed? I tried other suggestions posted by others in SO but no luck. Thanks in advance.

```
_surveySummaryTableViewController = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
//[_surveySummaryTableViewController setTableView:_surveySummaryTableView]; //This line commented out

UIBarButtonItem *doneItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(closeModalView:)];
[[_surveySummaryTableViewController navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem:doneItem];
[[_surveySummaryTableViewController navigationItem] setTitle:@"Response Summary"];
```

**===Additional info===**

Considering it works when the line above being commented,  the table actually populates a custom `UITableViewCell`. Could that be a problem?

Comment: You need to post the complete error message from the crash.

Comment: You present a `UINavigationController` in a `UIViewController`? You can, but it's not a normal practice. If I were you, I will use `UINavigationController` as parent, then push `UIViewController` when changing page.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor There is nothing wrong with presenting a modal nav controller from a vie controller.

Comment: @maddy: I didn't get any error msg for this. It simply crashes and the screen halts here 0x02a54756  <+0022>  call   0x2ba9a00 <dyld_stub_getpid> . Not sure what this is call, could be something related to memory? When I click the continue button (play button), nothing happens and it didn't pop out any msg in the console saying app is being terminated etc.

Comment: @rmaddy nothing wrong, yes. but in memory consumption wise, summoning `UINavigationController` will cause memory spikes (large memory consumption), which we probably want to avoid it.

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Huh? What memory spikes? It's very common to present a modal view controller in its own nav controller. Let's stick to the actual problem (which we don't really know yet).

Comment: @jason ,seeing your crash error, it suppose to me that it was an error of memory management, try putting breakpoints or enable zombie environment to figure that out.

Comment: @Parser: I have been thinking of that as well. Could be somewhere in my dealloc and all those release thingy. I actually enabled zombie but doesn't help much on this.

Comment: make a breakpoint in viewWillDisappear method and if its executing perfectly then put a breakpoint on viewWillAppear of coming viewcontroller.

Comment: @Parser, when I put a breakpoint in those methods, it doesn't go through them and the process doesn't break. The modal view just displays on screen without going thru those methods. This is the same for when it is being dismissed. Not going thru.

Comment: maybe you have this right, still check. _surveySummaryTableViewController -> retain. The base view of tableViewController should be strong, all the child views should be weak. I doubt you are in trouble because of retain cycles

Comment: @JeslyVarghese: thanks for heads up. I do changed the property of the child views to be `unsafe_unretained` yesterday but to no avail. Now that you mention about the strong property, when I change `_surveySummaryTableView` to be strong, it works! Will post the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the property type from `retain` to `strong` for `surveySummaryTableView`

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *surveySummaryTableView;`

And be sure to make the child views to be of type `weak` or `unsafe_unretained`

Thanks @JeslyVarghese & everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are pushing navController, you must dismiss that. Try:

```
[self.navigationController  dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

OR

```
[self.parentViewController.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue: "The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, however, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller."

Comment: The second one didn't dismiss the navController at all. I guess the `self.parentViewController.navigationController` is null. The first one executes but it crashes the same way as using `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`